# Change PL clock

Tags: clock, xilinx, programmable-logic, vivado

I'm designing my project in Vivado and I had a WNS (Worst negative Slack) of -2.67 ns (my PL clock was 200Mhz).

I had some problems when running my design since the results where good sometimes and bad other times and so I thought it could be related to this WNS.

I re-ran my design with PL frequency of 100MHz (the results are still good and bad but that's not relevant for this question) and my WNS is now of 0.22, which is ok.

I noticed something strange though:

When comparing the `xparameters.h` of my first and second designs the only difference that I noticed was the `XPAR_AXI_TIMER_0_CLOCK_FREQ_HZ`. the rest was exactly the same. changing the PL clock only changes that from one design to the other? That seems strange to me.

Also, using my timer with 100Mhz in my 2nd design, it took me 52830 clock cyles to run some part of the code in SDK. I went to `xparameters.h` and altered my `XPAR_AXI_TIMER_0_CLOCK_FREQ_HZ` to 200MHz, re-run my design and it took the same exact clock cycles to run that part of the code. Why is this, shouldn't it be half the clock cycles since the frequency is double?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xparameters.h` file should be considered read-only. It is automatically generated by Vivado and its purpose is to inform the software of the underlying hardware system. Changing it doesn't affect the hardware whatsoever; setting `XPAR_AXI_TIMER_0_CLOCK_FREQ_HZ` to 200MHz doesn't change the fact that the hardware used a 100MHz. It just lies about the hardware, and any software code that use that value will have wrong behaviour.

Beside, the number of clock cycles to perform an operation should not change when you modify the clock's frequency. If your code can do 1 addition per clock cycle, it does 1 addition per clock cycles whether the clock is 100MHz or 200MHz. Of course, at 200MHz it will execute twice as much additions as the 100MHz design in a second.

Finally, you should never run a design that doesn't pass timings, especially when it's failing by half the clock period. It's true that timings model are based on worst-case (bad process, highest temperature and lowest voltage), that it's pessimistic and that the failing path may never happen. Still, you are playing with fire, and your design will break at some point.

Comment: First of all, ty very much for all the help you've been giving me.
Just one question about your answer: what do you mean exactly by "your design will break at some point."?

Comment: It means it may stop working if you use it differently (load a different image for example), it may fail on another board due to process variations, stop working over time due to the temperature rising, etc. Basically, it's not robust and Xilinx tell you it won't work under the assumed operating conditions.

Comment: Ah ok, ty for the information. That's what I thought was the problem in the other [question that you answered](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/177451/strange-outputs-in-zedboard-sometimes) but unfortunately that wasn't it. I diminished my clock and the design is still behaving strangely